# What is the simplest, most portable way to send an email in elisp?

Tags: email, emacs, smtp, elisp

I'd like to write a little emacs command to send an email.  What's the simplest way to do this?  I know there are a lot of mail-sending plugins for emacs, but I really just need to send a simple little email.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works nicely:

```
(defun try-send-email (to subject body)
  "simple wrapper around message to send an email"
  (message-mail to subject)
  (message-goto-body)
  (insert body)
  (message-send-and-exit))
```

It does use [Gnus'](http://www.gnus.org/) message system (as opposed to the slightly simpler mail), but it does work in an Emacs w/out any configuration on my system.

Answer (score 2):

`C-x m` is simple enough.

Comment: That's true.  But I was wanting to send it programmatically.  It looks like compose-mail will bring up a new frame to compose the mail in.